# Problem with sourcing setup.bash

Tags: ros, catkin, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have some packages installed with apt, and some from from source in catkin_ws. The problem Im having is that the source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash file and the ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash file conflicts. As soon as I source catkin I can not find some packages In opt/ros, and as soon as I source opt/ros I can not find any of my catkin nodes. I have been struggling with this for a while now and Im wondering if it is a way of resolving this conflict?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259268/problem-with-sourcing-setup.bash/) by [Eirtrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/30027/eirtrand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2017-04-14**:
how do u try to find packages? are you using roscd? if you don't have opt/ros sourced the roscd command would not be even recognized ?? In other words I don't think you have your ros environment not sourced

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-14**:
or setup an alias setup="source devel/setup.sh" in your .bashrc or whatever shell you have there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your problem is u r sourcing the workspace locally in terminals and when you open a new one it is not sourced and you need to source again, to avoid it try to source your work space using .bashrc

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0